# Sitecore 8.2.3 preview error. Experience editor, ribbon error after upgrade

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.2

7.5 was converted to 8.2.3. Web site works on browser.
But when I preview a page in content editor, I get this error on the page:

url of the page = sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceEditor/Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId=

> [InvalidOperationException: Could not locate type
>   'Sitecore.Shell.Client.Speak.Layouts.Renderings.Resources.Pipelines.PipelineRenderingModel,Sitecore.Speak.Bootstrap3'.
>   Model reference:
>   'Sitecore.Shell.Client.Speak.Layouts.Renderings.Resources.Pipelines.PipelineRenderingModel,**Sitecore.Speak.Bootstrap3**']
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ModelLocator.GetModelFromTypeName(String
>   typeName, String model, Boolean throwOnTypeCreationError) +244
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel.GetFromRenderingItem.Process(GetModelArgs
>   args) +38    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +479
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter) +161
>
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetModel() +280
>
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Model() +30
>
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.ObjectExtensions.ValueOrDefault(T source,
>   Func`2 resultGetter) +57
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.get_Model() +150
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +221
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Renderings/Resources/Pipelines/Pipeline.cshtml'.
>   ]    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
>   +792    Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +75    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +479
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String
>   placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +183
>   (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +479
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String
>   placeholderName) +258
>   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml.Execute()
>   +1681    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252    System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +136    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +309
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml'
>   (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +792 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +75    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +479
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +301
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +375    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +88
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +831
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +831
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36

Comment: Errors like this a quite often caused by files from the old version that remained in place during the upgrade. Can you compare your sitecore and bin folder with those from a clean install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore.Speak.Bootstrap3 was the issue. In 7.5 the experience editor was customized with this [SDK](https://github.com/JakobChristensen/Sitecore.Speak.Bootstrap3.SDK). And we forgot about it during upgrade. Upgrade went well but it did not change he customization of experience editor in Core DB. Hence this problem occured. We solved it with taking corresponding item (21E86498-6C8E-4F3B-83F2-B49E5E0ABE16) from the vanilla installation of 8.2.3 and installed the package upgraded sitecore.

we got the item (21E86498-6C8E-4F3B-83F2-B49E5E0ABE16) by searching for 'Sitecore.Speak.Bootstrap3' text in Core DB .

Comment: I love Stackoverflow! I had the exact same problem. The item is at /sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 1/Layouts/Renderings/Resources/Pipeline